# What's a large production film called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Specifically, I mean a big budget film that casts famous actors and has a ton of staff and production crew. It should not matter whether the film is still in production or is already released.

A word that comes to mind is 'Blockbuster', but this word is only used for films that are a huge commercial success (i.e. already released).

Comment: I might say **epic**, but that implies a particular content. (I would hardly classify *The Avengers: Infinity War* as **epic**.) I think that **big budget** is going to be the best you can get.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts on the word 'epic'. It's also seems too big a word to describe your average big budget film. That word makes me think of written works that take an enormous amount of time (like decades) and effort to produce.

Comment: *Blockbuster* typically does refer to box office revenues (e.g., $100 million+ in the opening weekend) but can also refer to big budget movies that don't meet expectations (flop). A more generic term might be *tentpole* films or, more broadly, entertainment industry strategies that involve producing many things (films, tv series, etc.) in the hope that one of them will be a big hit, subsidizing the flops. Good examples of this are the many original tv series produced by HBO, Amazon, Netflix, Hulu, Showtime, etc., with only a few becoming 'viral' hits like *GoT, Orange is the New Black* etc

Comment: Sorry to point this out, and the use of "large production film" provides no confidence that any Answer could be useful.

Above and beyond that, any Answer would be personal preference or literary criticism or both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "Major Motion Picture" is used by those promoting their efforts at creating such a production. This would be useful before during and after the film was made.

Comment: This is the closest to the word I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds wierd, and "Major" implies success as much as Blockbuster. "Big budget" is far more precise.

Comment: I'd suggest that  "major motion picture" and "big budget" mean different things although many would be both.  "major motion picture" does suggest active promotion, which almost always accompanies a "big budget" film however an acclaimed and awaited movie on a serious subject , with major stars, and/or a well known novel could  be called a "Major motion picture" .  Hard to pin down because a 'quirky' film with Meryl Streep in might not be a "Major" but if it were a modest budget film with Meryl Streep playing Jackie Onasis with a limited release it still might be 'Major"

Comment: Toy Story sequel iw probably both Big Budget and "major" but maybe the 'Big Budget" feels more natural given the fun content ?

Comment: In my experience this term has been used by the most ambitious to promote the least likely to the most gullible.